# Every other factor in row to new column in R

Tags: r, formatting, format, dataframe, string-formatting

I have a quick reformatting question. I have a data frame of ~5000 factors with names and numbers such as this:

```
>df
1 Puppy
2 364547
3 Kitty
4 775833
5 Bunny
6 775984
```

And I want to transform it to look like this:

```
>df
1    Puppy    364547
2    Kitty    775833
3    Bunny    775984
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but certainly is not that efficient:

```
df<-c("Puppy",364547,"Kitty",775833,"Bunny",775984)

animals <- df[which(substr(df,1,1) %in% LETTERS)]
numbs <- df[which(substr(df,1,1) %in% seq(10,from=0))]

data.frame(animals,numbs)
```

Comment: ^Thanks guys! In the meantime, I also just made even and odd number sequences and just called the df rows from those. All three seemed to work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Here it is:

Creating the data frame:

```
df <- read.table(text=
"1 Puppy
2 364547
3 Kitty
4 775833
5 Bunny
6 775984")
```

Selecting what you want (explaining better, for the first column we get only the "first" elements so we have TRUE, FALSE; and for the second column we get only the "second" elements so we have FALSE, TRUE. `R` recycling takes care of the rest.):

```
df2 <- data.frame(V1=df$V2[c(TRUE, FALSE)], V2=df$V2[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
```

This will give you:

```
df2
  V1     V2
1 Puppy 364547
2 Kitty 775833
3 Bunny 775984
```

Answer (score 2):

The most direct thing that comes to mind for me is to use a `matrix`. Using @carloscinelli's sample data:

```
matrix(df$V2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1]    [,2]    
# [1,] "Puppy" "364547"
# [2,] "Kitty" "775833"
# [3,] "Bunny" "775984"
data.frame(matrix(df$V2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
#      X1     X2
# 1 Puppy 364547
# 2 Kitty 775833
# 3 Bunny 775984
```

Comment: Ananda Mahto, ingenious solution! @Tom A, maybe you could benchmark the solutions in your 5000 factors dataset to see which one is faster!

Comment: @carloscinelli, benchmarking won't really be fair if you're benchmarking the `matrix` approach simply because `data.frame`s are more expensive in terms of time than matrices in R (but with the added benefit of being able to hold columns of different types of data).